# Enabling AppArmor in Linux

Tags: linux-kernel, apparmor, lsm

I've compiled a kernel (linux-libre-xtreme) with [this configuration](https://git.parabola.nu/abslibre.git/plain/kernels/linux-libre-xtreme/config.x86_64), it has most LSMs enabled: YAMA, SMACK, AppArmor, TOMOYO and SELinux. However, when I start the apparmor service with OpenRC I get:

```
# rc-service apparmor start
 * Stopping AppArmor ...
 *   Unloading AppArmor profiles
 *   Root privileges not available                                                                                                                                [ !! ]
 * Starting AppArmor ...
 *   Loading AppArmor profiles ...
Cache read/write disabled: interface file missing. (Kernel needs AppArmor 2.4 compatibility patch.)
Warning: unable to find a suitable fs in /proc/mounts, is it mounted?
Use --subdomainfs to override.
 *   /etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.apache2 failed to load
Cache read/write disabled: interface file missing. (Kernel needs AppArmor 2.4 compatibility patch.)
Warning: unable to find a suitable fs in /proc/mounts, is it mounted?
Use --subdomainfs to override.
```

And other profiles also complain, however this doesn't happen with other kernel that I've compiled too (linux-libre-lts-apparmor, see its configuration [here](https://git.parabola.nu/abslibre.git/plain/kernels/linux-libre-lts-apparmor/config.x86_64))

What am I doing wrong? If I do `cat /sys/module/apparmor/parameters/enabled` with the linux-libre-xtreme kernel, I get `N`, but with linux-libre-lts-apparmor, it says `Y`, so I know it's not something with kernel parameters from the bootloader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by disabling `CONFIG_DEFAULT_SECURITY_DAC=y`, there has to be only one `CONFIG_DEFAULT_SECURITY_*` enabled it seems

**EDIT:** I also discovered that, for AppArmor to be enabled by default when booting, SECURITY_APPARMOR_BOOTPARAM_VALUE must be set to "1", like this: `CONFIG_SECURITY_APPARMOR_BOOTPARAM_VALUE=1`